# Arrow with multiple turns in Libreoffice Draw?

Tags: microsoft-visio, diagrams, libreoffice-draw

I want to draw an arrow between two objects in LibreOffice Draw. For simplicity suppose they're rectangular and even that they have those "connection points" and the arrow connects those.

Now, I don't want it to be straight arrow, I want it to turn and circumnavigate other elements on my canvas And - there's more than two bends, so it's more than just straight - 90 deg turn - straight - 90 deg turn - straight, it can be any number of turns.

I know Visio has an arrow widget in which you can create additional segments dynamically, while in LibreOffice I see just the simple up-to-three-segments version.  I suppose I could manually draw multiple line segments that each end where the next starts, but then I would not be able to drag the objects around without the segments getting disconnected.

Comment: Never had a lot of success trying to really draw a diagram in OO... for my UML class last term I used https://draw.io and it worked great, and copy/pasting the resulting image into my OO doc Just Worked.

Comment: @ivanivan: Doesn't look like that has the feature I'm looking for.